# JSON File w/Black Text vs Red Text on Xcode

Tags: json, xcode

I downloaded a tutorial for JSON that has a ".json" file already loaded with red font that appears like the following:

[image]

I have another file that I converted online using a CSV to JSON converter, then I simply dragged/dropped the file into Xcode. It has black text like the following:

[image]

Is there some way of creating a .json file within Xcode? I looked around the inspector as well and they both have the exact same Identity/Type options selected. I'm new to json, thus my question around it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the second file extension?

Comment: They both have .json file extensions.

Comment: Sometimes reopening the file later causes it to be syntax-highlighted properly. Happened to me before with xml or html, I think...

Comment: So that worked for one json file that I have (thank you, and I feel sheepish that was all it was), but I have another one that is massive (30k rows+) that is still black. Wondering if there is a capacity or something. Is there a better option over json for tons of info? For example, the text of the bible, I was going to use json, but would you use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click your project folder and choose "New File..."

Within the iOS section, choose "Other". Then choose "Empty". Click Next.

In the "Save As" box, enter a file name with an extension of .json